# How to resolve "Cannot resolve 'file'" error in webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack

I keep getting this really annoying error in webpack and even when I run `webpack --display-error-details`, I get no errors. But anytime I run `webpack-dev-server` I get the following error. I really can't see where I am going wrong in my configuration.

```
Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' 
./frontend/app.jsx
```

---

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './frontend/app.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname 
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [ /\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss' ]
  }
};
```

---

```
{
  "name": "basicapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.jsx",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env development",
    "dev-server": "nodemon ./server.js localhost 8080",
    "build": "webpack --env production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, what is your folder structure? seems like the file called ./frontend/app.jsx is not in the same folder that your context: __dirname

Answer (score 0):

Webpack may not be treating __dirname as you want it to and may be resolving it to / instead. Try adding this to your webpack config:

```
{
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be because of multiple reasons the best way to identify the exact issue is to tryout the below two commands:

if you are running webpack 1/2 alone then use the snippet:

```
webpack --display-error-details
```

if you are running the webpack dev server then use the snippet:

```
webpack-dev-server --display-error-details
```

this would provide a detailed error report in the console